# Does MassTransit support detached Entity Framework graphs?

Tags: entity-framework-6, rabbitmq, masstransit

The system I'm developing uses MassTransit to communicate between modules.  I've generated numerous messages and it was working great.  But I'm running into an issue with messages that contain Entity Framework 6 generated types.  Flat model objects publish fine, but when I try to send a detached object graph it fails.

I only get this generic error:

```
[Error] - Send Fault: rabbitmq://127.0.0.1:5672/...
[Debug] - The model usage threw an exception
[Debug] - The connection usage threw an exception
[Debug] - The connection threw an exception
```

Are EF6 objects supported with MassTransit/RabbitMQ?  I've not been able to find documentation either way.

Not sure where to go from here...

Answer (score 1):

It's probably not what you want to hear, but messages shouldn't contain your persistence types - even if it works, it's short term gain/long term loss. Conceptually messages represent delta/change in state, while persistence reflects applied change - final state, possibly at certain point in time. If you work against this, sooner or later you'll have a big problem, like having to reconcile multiple/concurrent updates on a whole record/hierarchy.

Comment: In general, I agree.  But in this case I have a couple of cases where potentially all of the persisted data needs to be passed along.